# Beginner Help: Unable to get form variables working in PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, forms

I jut recently started learning PHP from a book called PHP/MySQL Programming for the Absolute Beginner by Andy Harris.

In one of his samples, he writes that this code should function (I've cut it short a bit):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Choices</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Font Choices</h1>
<h3>Demonstrates how to read HTML form elements</h3>

<form method = "post"
      action = "borderMaker.php">


<h3>Text to modify</h3>
<textarea name = "basicText"
      rows = "10"
      cols = "40">
blah blah
</textarea>



<input type = "submit"
       value = "show me">

</form>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in Bordermaker.php something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Output</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Your Output</h1>
<center>
<?


print $basicText;

?>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

But when i try to run it it says I can't find the $basicText variable.

I'm currently learning PHP with XAMPP running on my computer.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When you hit the submit button from your forms page, are the variables being sent in the url string when it tries to transfer pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `$_POST['basicText']` instead of `$basicText`

You are using the `"post"` method on your form so all your input values will be contained in an array called `$_POST`.

If you were using `"get"` as your method, all the form information would be passed as a query string on the end of your url, and you would access them with an array called `$_GET` the same way.

Comment: @Kevin You should make his answer as correct if it helped you out :)

Answer (score 1):

This example relies on the usage of [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) to function. What this means is that every variable submitted via form becomes a global variable, which means random-joe can inject unknown variables into your code. This has been deprecated as of 5.3 and will be removed in later versions.

I highly recommend finding a book based on later versions of PHP to learn from, preferably something tailored to PHP 5 (at minimum).